# Unity- Game Collectable Not Playing Sound Effect

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a script set on a collectible where if the current object is triggered by the object tagged "Player" it should play a sound, update the score and destroy itself. Now, updating the score and destroying the object works fine but the sound doesn't get played. I'm not quite sure why. Here's the code:

```
    [SerializeField] private float cherries=0;
    [SerializeField] private Text score;
    [SerializeField] private AudioSource ad;
    

    private void Start() {
    }
    

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision) {
        if(collision.tag=="Player" ){
            ad.Play();
            cherries+=1;
            score.text=cherries.ToString();
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
```

Comment: Please include your audio source configuration. Is the a clip assigned to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use an audio source on the object being collected you'll need to make sure it is alive long enough to play the clip.

```
    ad.Play();
     // Use delayed Destroy overload to give it time to play before the object is destroyed
    Destroy(gameObject, 1f);
```

However, I would recommend centralizing your audio on a singleton audio manager using PlayOneShot(AudioClip) so that you can offload the playing of the audio clips and let objects be destroyed when they should.

**Here is an example using an AudioManager**

```
public AudioManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
  public static AudioManager Instance {get; private set;}
  [SerializeField]
  private AudioClip _cherriesAudioClip; // Assign through inspector
  [SerializeField]
  private AudioSource _audioSource; // Assign through inspector

  void Awake()
  {
    // Make sure there isn't another instance already
    if (Instance != null)
    {
      Destroy(gameObject);
      return;
    }
    // Instantiate the static game object instance
    Instance = this;
    // Make sure it stays alive
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
  }

  /// Call from another script to play your clip
  public void PlayCherriesPickup()
  {    
    _audioSource.PlayOneShot(cherriesAudioClip);
  }
```

And then you call it from your collectable script using the static instance like so

```
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision) 
    {
      if(collision.tag=="Player" )
      {
        AudioManager.Instance.PlayCherriesPickup();
        cherries += 1;
        score.text=cherries.ToString();
        Destroy(gameObject); // No need to delay the destroy
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hi. First of all thank you so much for the suggestion. I tried out your method but it didn't work either. That's when I found out that the reason was because my game object was getting destroyed before it could play the audio. I managed to fix it by using the WaitForSeconds() method. Now it works, but with a game object being destroyed just a little late. Thanks a lot

Comment: Oh yeah, I should have caught that! You can also use the overload of Destroy which takes a float for a delay before destroying: Destroy(gameObject, 1f);. However, it would be even better to move the playing of audio to your player (or even better - to an AudioManger script) using various audio clips and PlayOneShot() by calling the necessary method from collision instead of having an audio source on each collectable. Then you could make the call to say, AudioManager.PlayCherriesPickup(), and let the cherry be destroyed immediately.

Comment: @Nayeer Mahiuddin, I've updated my answer to reflect what you found, and also added an example using an AudioManager to centralize your audio clips, and allow objects to focus on what they need to do

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I truly appreciate it. I am gonna try it out and see how it works. Again, I truly appreciate the effort man

Comment: No problem. Just realized I had forgot to include .Instance when calling a method on AudioManager. Updated usage example